# Raise 10 to a power in javascript, are there better ways than this

Tags: javascript, exponentiation

I have a need to create an integer value to a specific power (that's not the correct term, but basically I need to create 10, 100, 1000, etc.)  The "power" will be specified as a function parameter.  I came up with a solution but MAN does it feel hacky and wrong.  I'd like to learn a better way if there is one, maybe one that isn't string based?  Also, eval() is not an option.

Here is what I have at this time:

```
function makeMultiplierBase(precision)
{
    var numToParse = '1';
    for(var i = 0; i < precision; i++)
    {
        numToParse += '0';
    }

    return parseFloat(numToParse);
}
```

I also just came up with this non-string based solution, but still seems hacky due to the loop:

```
function a(precision)
{
    var tmp = 10;
    for(var i = 1; i < precision; i++)
    {
        tmp *= 10;
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

BTW, I needed to do this to create a rounding method for working with currency.  I had been using 
    var formatted = Math.round(value * 100) / 100

but this code was showing up all over the place and I wanted to have a method take care of the rounding to a specific precision so I created this

```
if(!Math.roundToPrecision)
{
    Math.roundToPrecision = function(value, precision)
    {
        Guard.NotNull(value, 'value');

        b = Math.pow(10, precision);
        return Math.round(value * b) / b;
    }  
}
```

Thought I'd include this here as it's proven to be handy already.

Comment: so, why are you making it a float and not instead making it an integer?

Comment: @Shad You are referring to the parseFloat() call?  If so, I suppose that's just an oversight, Number(numToParse) would work too

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In ES5 and earlier, use `Math.pow`:

```
var result = Math.pow(10, precision);
```

```js
var precision = 5;
var result = Math.pow(10, precision);
console.log(result);
```

In ES2016 and later, use the [exponentiation operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-exp-operator):

```
let result = 10 ** precision;
```

```js
let precision = 5;
let result = 10 ** precision;
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Sad to say, I wasn't aware of the pow() method, it's exactly what I needed.  However, I'd still like to learn how it's done; any idea what Math.pow() may be doing behind the covers?

Comment: @Steve, like most math libraries they probably implement numerical approximations of functions with the standards-required precision. Since `Math.pow` isn't just for integers, it's implementation has to be generic for all "real" numbers so it's not something similar to your loop implementation (which wouldn't work on a base of say, 5.672 for example); Maybe a taylor expansion or something similar.

Comment: @Davin - I googled "taylor expansion" and upon reading the first paragraph from Wikipedia blood began trickling from my ears as my vision blurred...  I will just accept that Math.pow() is cool.  ;0)

Comment: @Steve, hmmm, so you can rework the equation as follows: we want the value of `y=x^n`, so we write `ln(y) = ln(x^n) = n*ln(x)` and raising both sides to the power of the natural base `e` we get `y = exp(n*ln(x))` and now you can calculate `ln(x)` with a taylor expansion to any required precision in a predetermined number of steps, multiple by `n`, and calculate the `exp` function of the product, again with a taylor expansion to the required number of terms i.e. the required precision.

Comment: @Steve, yeah, those wiki articles are written to make us all feel dumb :) Or to make their authors feel smart. In any case, if you pick up a text book on real analysis their should be sufficient material to understand taylor expansions to quite some depth, although that blood-from-the-ears symptom might return.

Comment: @Davin Thanks for the additional info, it demystifies some of what was said earlier.

Answer (score 4):

Why not:

```
function precision(x) {  
  return Math.pow(10, x);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This has the same result as your function, but i still don't understand the application/intention.

```
function makeMultiplierBase(precision,base){
    return Math.pow(base||10,precision);
}
```

Comment: Why not just `return Math.pow(base||10, precision);`

Comment: @davin True, just an initialization habit =)

Answer (score 3):

if all you need to do is raise 10 to  different powers, or any base to any power why not use the built in `Math.pow(10,power);` unless you have soe specific need to reason to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 2):

For powers at 10³³ and above, `Math.pow()` may lose precision.  For example:

```
Math.pow(10, 33);    //-> 1.0000000000000001e+33
Math.pow(10, 34);    //-> 1.0000000000000001e+34
Math.pow(10, 35);    //-> 1e+35
Math.pow(10, 36);    //-> 1e+36
Math.pow(10, 37);    //-> 1.0000000000000001e+37
```

While not an everyday problem that you may run into in JavaScript, it could be quite troublesome in some situations, particularly with comparison operators.  One example is Google's [`log10Floor()`](https://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/closure/goog/math/math.js#385) function from the Closure Library:

```
/**
 * Returns the precise value of floor(log10(num)).
 * Simpler implementations didn't work because of floating point rounding
 * errors. For example
 * <ul>
 * <li>Math.floor(Math.log(num) / Math.LN10) is off by one for num == 1e+3.
 * <li>Math.floor(Math.log(num) * Math.LOG10E) is off by one for num == 1e+15.
 * <li>Math.floor(Math.log10(num)) is off by one for num == 1e+15 - 1.
 * </ul>
 * @param {number} num A floating point number.
 * @return {number} Its logarithm to base 10 rounded down to the nearest
 *     integer if num > 0. -Infinity if num == 0. NaN if num < 0.
 */
goog.math.log10Floor = function(num) {
  if (num > 0) {
    var x = Math.round(Math.log(num) * Math.LOG10E);
    return x - (Math.pow(10, x) > num);
  }
  return num == 0 ? -Infinity : NaN;
};
```

If you pass a power of 10 above 10³³, this function could return an incorrect result because `Math.pow(10, 33) > 1e33` evaluates to `true`.  The way I worked around this is to use Number coercion, concatenating the exponent to '1e':

```
+'1e33'    //-> 1e+33
+'1e34'    //-> 1e+34
+'1e35'    //-> 1e+35
+'1e36'    //-> 1e+36
+'1e37'    //-> 1e+37
```

And, fixing the `log10Floor()` function:

```
goog.math.log10Floor = function(num) {
  if (num > 0) {
    var x = Math.round(Math.log(num) * Math.LOG10E);
    return x - (+('1e' + x) > num);
  }
  return num == 0 ? -Infinity : NaN;
};
```

**Note**: The bug in closure library has since been [fixed](https://code.google.com/p/closure-library/issues/detail?id=633).

Answer (score -1):

Use a lookup table. But if this is for rounding currency amounts, you should be using BigDecimal instead of the entire schemozzle.

Answer (score -1):

I just stumbled on something while going through https://github.com/aecostas/huffman. The compiled code(js) has a line

```
alphabet_next = sorted.slice(0, +(sorted.length - 1 - groupsize) + 1 || 9e9);
```

If you try to evaluate 9e9 (on the node and browser console) it gives you 9000000000 which is "9*10^9".Based on that you could simply do the below to get the 10th power.

    `var n = 2;
    eval("1e"+n); //outputs 100`

EDIT: More on exponential notation from 
http://www.2ality.com/2012/03/displaying-numbers.html.

> There are two decimal notations used by JavaScript: Fixed notation
>   [ "+" | "-" ] digit+ [ "." digit+ ]
>   and exponential notation
>   [ "+" | "-" ] digit [ "." digit+ ] "e" [ "+" | "-" ] digit+
>   An example of exponential notation is -1.37e+2. For output, there is always exactly one digit before the point, for input you can use more than one digit. Exponential notation is interpreted as follows: Given a number in exponential notation:
>       *significand e exponent*.
>   The value of that number is
>   *significand* × 10<sup>exponent</sup>.
>   Hence, -1.37e+2 represents the number −137.

Comment: Read the question and you can find there: ".... Also, eval() is not an option."